# C# - is there a way to get the local path of the Default FTP site?

Tags: c#, active-directory, iis-6, ftp, directoryentry

Is there a way to get the local path of the Default FTP site (in IIS) programmatically?

Like C:\program files\ftproot, shown below:

[image]

I'd imagine it would be something like:

```
DirectoryEntry ftproot = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/MSFTPSVC/1/Root");
string directory; // = ftproot.something
```

Any ideas?

Edit:  This would be for IIS 6.0.  Surely this has got to be stored somewhere - maybe in the registry?

Comment: This article might help (IIS7 only): - [Automating IIS administration with C#](http://forums.iis.net/t/1150298.aspx) Code in the second reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IIS 6 at least, I found it in the registry here:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\MSFtpsvc\Parameters\Virtual Roots\

Format of the data is a little strange - for instance, D:\ftproot,,1

[image]

Comment: I'm curious as to what that middle value is in D:\ftproot,,1.  It looks like that last value is the sum of the read and write rights, where read = 1, and write = 2.

Answer (score 2):

From what I know, there are two Active Directory attributes: msIIS-FTPRoot, msIIS-FTPDir.

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878070.aspx)

Basically, the user's home folder is determined upon authentication by querying the msIIS-FTPRoot and msIIS-FTPDir attributes of the user object in Active Directory. The concatenation of the msIIS-FTPRoot and msIIS-FTPDir values results in the path to the user's home folder.

An example may look like this:

```
  msIIS-FTPRoot = D:\FTP Users
  msIIS-FTPDir = \JohnSmith
```

This will result in "D:\FTP Users\JohnSmith" as the home folder for the user.

Code to traverse all the users and there default directories:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
            {            
                string domain = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERDNSDOMAIN");
                string dc = GetDC(domain);
                string ldap = String.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", domain, dc);
                DirectoryEntry e = new DirectoryEntry(ldap);

                DirectorySearcher src = new DirectorySearcher(e, "(objectClass=user)");
                SearchResultCollection res = src.FindAll();
                foreach (SearchResult r in res)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry f = r.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    Console.WriteLine(f.Name + "\t" + f.Properties["msIIS-FTPRoot"].Value + f.Properties["msIIS-FTPDir"].Value);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

private static string GetDC(string domain)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(domain);
            sb.Replace(".", ",DC=");
            sb.Insert(0, "DC=");
            return sb.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, where is GetDC() defined?